# GetRandomValue function in Raylib giving 0 every time

Tags: c, raylib

I'm trying to make a snake game in Raylib. I've gotten to the stage of writing a cell (food) to the screen, this is my code:

```
#include "raylib.h"

#define CELLSIZE 30
#define CELLCOUNT 25

Color green = {173, 204, 96, 255};
Color darkGreen = {43, 51, 24, 255};


int main(void){

        Vector2 foodPos = {GetRandomValue(0, CELLCOUNT - 1),GetRandomValue(0, CELLCOUNT - 1)};


        InitWindow(CELLSIZE * CELLCOUNT, CELLSIZE * CELLCOUNT, "retro snake");
        SetTargetFPS(60);
        BeginDrawing();


        while (!WindowShouldClose())
        {
                BeginDrawing();
                ClearBackground(green);

                DrawRectangle(foodPos.x, foodPos.y, CELLSIZE, CELLSIZE, darkGreen);

                EndDrawing();
        }

        CloseWindow();

        return 0;
}
```

When I run this code the food is always in the top left corner - it just spawns the food at *0,0* every time.

[This is what it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llO27.png)

Comment: Have you considered that you're really, _really_ lucky? On a realistic note, make sure you're compiling with all warning flags, and run it in a debugger to ensure your code is running as you expect within that loop.

Comment: Have you seeded the Random number generator?

Comment: Shouldn't your `DrawRectangle()` be multiplying the x and y coords by the `CELLSIZE`?

Comment: Whats seeding? I'm not sure what you mean Syntactics?

Comment: Also, it should have been multiplied by CELLSIZE , but it did'nt fix the main issue

Comment: Seeding is the act of providing an initial value (a [seed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed)) to a [pseudorandom number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator). The sequence produced by the pRNG is determined by this value.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are calling `GetRandomValue` without first calling `SetRandomSeed`.

```
void SetRandomSeed(unsigned int seed); // Set the seed for the random number generator
```

As of Raylib 5, there are two possible [pRNGs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator): C's standard [`rand`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/rand) ([`srand`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/srand)), and [`rprand`](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/blob/master/src/external/rprand.h) - an implementation of *xoshiro128***.

If the standard C pRNG is in use, calling `rand()` without first calling `srand(seed)` behaves as though `srand(1)` was called during program startup. In this situation, it is *extremely* likely you would see non-zero values - but since the seed is always the same (`1`), they would be the same values on every execution of the program.

If `rprand` is in use, calling the internal `rprand_xoshiro` without first calling `rprand_set_seed` results in a pRNG with a zero-state: all numbers generated will be zero. I would hazard a guess that this is what is occurring on your system (in effect: when you call `GetRandomValue` before `SetRandomSeed`).

---

`InitWindow` calls

```
SetRandomSeed((unsigned int)time(NULL));
```

as the last thing it does, and is often the first Raylib library function called in an application, so you can simply reorder the code:

```
InitWindow(CELLSIZE * CELLCOUNT, CELLSIZE * CELLCOUNT, "retro snake");
SetTargetFPS(60);

Vector2 foodPos = {
    GetRandomValue(0, CELLCOUNT - 1),
    GetRandomValue(0, CELLCOUNT - 1)
};
```

---

As [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77969409/getrandomvalue-function-in-raylib-giving-0-every-time#comment137456441_77969409) by [@pmacfarlane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19639413/pmacfarlane), your coordinates, which are in the range `[0, CELLSIZE)` must be multiplied by `CELLSIZE` for the rectangle to be drawn at the correct offset.

Additionally note that the first `BeginDrawing();` (outside the loop) is erroneous.

A working example (press <kbd>SPACE</kbd> to move the rectangle to a random position):

```
#include <raylib.h>

#define CELLSIZE 30
#define CELLCOUNT 25
#define RANDOM_CELL() (GetRandomValue(0, CELLCOUNT - 1))

Color green = { 173, 204, 96, 255 };
Color darkGreen = { 43, 51, 24, 255 };

int main(void)
{
    const int dim = CELLCOUNT * CELLSIZE;
    InitWindow(dim, dim, "retro snake");
    SetTargetFPS(60);

    Vector2 foodPos = { RANDOM_CELL(), RANDOM_CELL() };

    while (!WindowShouldClose()) {
        if (IsKeyPressed(KEY_SPACE)) {
            foodPos.x = RANDOM_CELL();
            foodPos.y = RANDOM_CELL();
        }

        BeginDrawing();
        ClearBackground(green);
        DrawRectangle(foodPos.x * CELLSIZE, foodPos.y * CELLSIZE, CELLSIZE, CELLSIZE, darkGreen);
        EndDrawing();
    }

    CloseWindow();
}
```

[image: proto-snake-gif]